# In Magnific popup(type:Iframe), Slick slider not working in ios device

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, iframe

When I using Magnific popup(type:iframe),Inside of that popup Slick slider is not working in IOS devices like iphone,ipad. If any one have fix for this issue please help

please note: it only happens in IOS devices.

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle that reproduces this issue? If we can't see the issue or the code that you're using, then it's virtually impossible for us to help you.

Comment: Here is the file path
https://jsfiddle.net/dt8rw389/5/


Im targetting index1.html contains simple slick slider